# spring-boot azure spring data cosmos Like returning empty

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Using cosmos with spring boot.

This does no work

```
public interface UsersRespository extends CosmosRepository<User, String>  {

  @Query("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name LIKE \"%@searchString%\"")
  List<User> search(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

but this works

```
public interface UsersRespository extends CosmosRepository<User, String>  {
    
      @Query("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name LIKE \"%mm%\"")
      List<User> search(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

This also works

```
  public interface UsersRespository extends CosmosRepository<User, String>  {
        
          @Query("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name = '@searchString'")
          List<User> search(@Param("searchString") String searchString);
```

any idea why?

Comment: using azure-spring-data-cosmos 3.9.0

Comment: can you try to make manual concatenation  to the query without using @Param , that means you make manual concatenation of query + searchString.
i know that you already tested with %mm% but lets try concatenation to make sure that searchString have a good value.

Comment: @Houssem Thanks for your reply. I do not think i can pass variables to "@Query". import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.Query;

Comment: For others facing this issue https://github.com/fergesch/Enca-Eats-backend/blob/c0cf94c868df33f2581d61789175a158cd49ddf6/src/main/java/com/fergesch/encaeats/dao/GenericCosmosDao.java helped

Comment: but do not know why the above does not work

Comment: SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name  LIKE '%@searchString%'
 > param: @searchString= cog

Comment: Added as a bug https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/23386